# Storing JOIN Values in PHP and showing them as a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have following SQL query:

```
SELECT tbltasks.fldTaskNr
    ,tbltasks.fldRITMNr
    ,tbltasks.fldCHGNr
    ,tblci.fldCI
    ,tblgxp.fldGxP
    ,tblrequester.fldRequester
    ,tblstatus.fldStatus
    ,tbltasks.fldDescription
    ,tblresponsible.fldResponsible
    ,tbllocation.fldLocation
FROM tbltasks
LEFT JOIN tblCI ON tblci.pkCI = tbltasks.fkCI
LEFT JOIN tblgxp ON tblgxp.pkGxP = tbltasks.fkGxP
LEFT JOIN tblrequester ON tblrequester.pkRequester = tbltasks.fkRequester
LEFT JOIN tblstatus ON tblstatus.pkStatus = tbltasks.fkStatus
LEFT JOIN tblresponsible ON tblresponsible.pkResponsible = tbltasks.fkResponsible
LEFT JOIN tbllocation ON tbllocation.pkLocation = tbltasks.fkLocation
```

OUTPUT:
[image: Query output]

Now I want to store the values of this query and output them as a table, should look like this:
[image: Table]

I got the following table as HTML, the output should show in this table and repeat itself as there will be several entries in the database:

```
                    <th>Task Nr.</th>
                    <th>RITM Nr.</th>
                    <th>CHG Nr.</th>
                    <th>CI</th>
                    <th>GxP</th>
                    <th>Task Requester</th>
                    <th>Task Status</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Responsible</th>
                    <th style="width: 201px;">Location</th>
                </tr>
```

How can I do that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's difficult to give specific advice unless you show us a bit of your php code. Please [edit] your question, and look for tutorials about using SQL from within php.

Comment: Hello, that's the problem. I yet don't have any php code, because I don't know where to start. KR

Comment: Teaching you to access SQL from php is far beyond the scope of StackOverflow answers. Here's an [example tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/index.htm) with some background.

Comment: Okay, Thanks O. Jones. In that case I had the wrong idea about StackOverflow. Would  this [link](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display-table-data/)  be appropriate for my problem?

Comment: That tutorial looks good to me.  Don't hesitate to ask another question if you have problems implementing your php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy but process is little bit long.
First make sure to give your query column an name value as follow:

```
SELECT tbltasks.fldTaskNr AS "TASK_NR"
,tbltasks.fldRITMNr AS "RITMNR"
,tbltasks.fldCHGNr AS "CHGNR"
,tblci.fldCI AS "FLDCI"
,tblgxp.fldGxP AS "GXP"
,tblrequester.fldRequester AS "REQUESTER"
,tblstatus.fldStatus AS "FLD_STATUS"
,tbltasks.fldDescription AS "FLD_DESCRIPTION"
,tblresponsible.fldResponsible AS "RESPONSIBLE"
,tbllocation.fldLocation AS "LOCATION" FROM tbltasks .. (rest of your joints)
```

Then use this code to convert your query into a array of object

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row; 
} 
return $data;
```

Once this step is done then we can move on to your HTML Table part

```
<tr>
<th>Task Nr.</th>
<th>RITM Nr.</th>
<th>CHG Nr.</th>
<th>CI</th>
<th>GxP</th>
<th>Task Requester</th>
<th>Task Status</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Responsible</th>
<th style="width: 201px;">Location</th>
</tr>

<?php
for($i = 0 ;$i < count($data); $i++){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$data['TASK_NR'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['RITMNR'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['CHGNR'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['FLDCI'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['GXP'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['REQUESTER'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['FLD_STATUS'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['FLD_DESSCRIPTION'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$data['RESPONSIBLE'].'</td>';
echo '<td style="width: 201px;">'.$data['LOCATION'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem, and make sure your file extension is ".php"

Answer (score -1):

You can print the data you pulled into html with foearch.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    <tr>
       <td>
          <?php echo $val ?>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

}

You can get the result you want by applying the above code to your own table and data.

Comment: First : this piece of code itself would not run since you are putting html in php code section out of nowhere. Second : this does not provide an answer to the question since the OP isn't even close to this part ( only PHP is running, since he has PMA). So no access to data in PHP code, and we don't know anything about how he would want to display those informations (the technical stack)

Comment: are you serious how does html code not work in php? If you are aware, it is trying to make a table above and it will pull the data from the db, then it will print the data into html with foreach, it's that bro

Comment: Your code : https://www.tehplayground.com/lvfNlSJhwqlEfhaV; something that 'could' work : https://www.tehplayground.com/CY8Cckjx0yY8DnjN